# Modifying N+1th element in an array at Nth iteration?

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently doing a data analysis project involving text mining. As of now, I am stuck on filtering out certain phrases.

Suppose I have this tokenized array of words

```
arr = ['hello' ',' , 'how', 'is' , 'your', 'day', 'going', '?' , '#', 'HelloWorld']
```

(hello, how is your day going? #HelloWorld)

and I want to remove the    `#HelloWorld`  from the sentence.

My original logic was traverse through the array and check for the `#` , once it the `#` has been found, I would replace the `#` and the element after the `#` with a blank space as followed:

```
N = 0
for index to arr:
    if arr[N] == '#':
        arr[N] = (' ')
        arr[N+1] = (' ')
    N += 1
```

unfortunately, I got the error `list assignment index out of range` at line 5. I tried to use the `.append()` but it only allows modification at `N` .

Is there another approach to this?

Comment: Do you mean `for index in arr:`?

Comment: Your code should work unless the *last* element of the list is `#`. Then `arr[N+1]` is outside the array.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, like the others said, you need to check when you are at the end of the list.

EDIT: simplify !

```
arr = ['a', 'b', '#', 'aa']
indices = [idx for idx, elt in enumerate(arr) if elt == '#']

for idx in indices:
    if idx != len(arr): arr[idx+1] = ' '  # Check if not at the end of the list
    arr[idx] = ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will try to access outside the array when the last element is `#`, so you need to check for that.

There's also no need to use a separate variable for iteration and indexing, just iterate over the range of indexes.

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == '#':
        arr[i] = ' '
        if i < len(arr)-2:
            arr[i+1] = ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your codes is 'N+1' will be out of range when loop to the end of the list.

If one element must exist following one '#', try below:

```
arr = ['hello' ',' , 'how', 'is' , 'your', 'day', 'going', '?' , '#', 'HelloWorld']

for index in range(0, len(arr)):
    if arr[index] == '#':
        arr[index:index+2] = ['', '']
print (arr)
```

Output:

```
['hello,', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day', 'going', '?', '', '']
[Finished in 0.133s]
```

if the array is end with '#', it will still replace '#' with `['','']` ( I am not sure whether this result is as you expected.

```
arr = ['hello' ',' , 'how', 'is' , 'your', 'day', 'going', '?' , '#', 'HelloWorld', '#']

for index in range(0, len(arr)):
    if arr[index] == '#':
        arr[index:index+2] = ['', '']
print (arr)
```

Output:

```
['hello,', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day', 'going', '?', '', '', '', '']
[Finished in 0.179s]
```